# laravel 5 controller not visible via browser

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know laravel 5 isnt out yet and in development stages but I have been playing around with it to try and understand how it works. Using the HomeController, i added another method called contact and when i try to visit it via the browser it just show a 404 page. What am i doing wrong? By default routes are disabled and everything is passed through the controllers.

```
http://domain.com/home/contact

<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = array(
            'fname' => 'sarmen',
            'lname' => 'b'
        );

        return view('pages.home')->with('data', $data);
    }

    public function contact()
    {
        return 'contact us';
    }

}
```

in

```
app/Providers/RouteServiceProviders.php
```

this line

```
require app_path('Http/routes.php');
```

is commented out. So i just uncommented it and put this into my routes.php

```
$router->get('contact', 'HomeController@contact');
```

and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the solution here and also a link for reference, not only the link:

From [Laracast forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/controller-class-not-found):

> You need to specify the full path:

```
App\Http\Controllers\HomeController
```

> Either that, or add a namespace to the RouteServiceProvider section, where you require routes.php - like this:

```
public function map(Router $router) {
    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->rootUrlNamespace], 
          function() use   ($router) {
             require app_path('Http/routes.php');
          });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution thanks to jeffrey way

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/controller-class-not-found